# Alternative to UART/I2C LCD displays?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd, uart

I'm building a MIDI synthesizer on Arduino Uno, and am considering user interface options.

I see on Adafruit and Sparkfun there are 16x2 LCD panels available that interface via I2C serial or by UART, but I think neither of those will work in my application:

- The UART is clocked at 31250 baud to receive MIDI, and that's not a supported baud rate for these LCD devices;
- I'm producing audio by driving an external DAC (MCP4725) over full-speed I2C; any transmission to another device would audibly jitter the DAC output;
- SoftwareSerial would get around the UART clocking problem, but I believe it would stall the main loop while driving the output.

One option might be to roll my own software serial routine, carefully clocking it on the main loop, which (I believe) reliably runs at either 14.8KHz or 22.2KHz depending on the DAC protocol in use. I could set a SparkFun SerLCD into a slow data rate (2400 baud) and count passes through the main loop to time the data output.

Another option would be to use a secondary MCU -- I have a surplus Trinket M0 on hand -- and define a custom synchronous serial protocol between the two MCUs, and have the secondary relay commands to the LCD but that's getting into Rube Goldberg territory.

Any obvious options I'm overlooking?

Comment: Old 16x2 LCDs doesn't have an *interface* really, just a bunch of cables to connect to some unused pins. Modern OLED comes in I2C and SPI versions.

Comment: Also consider using an Arduino Mega, which has 4 UARTs.

Comment: @LookAlterno: IIRC, it's a sort of synchronous, either 8-bits or 4-bits, parallel interface.

Comment: There are a few interrupt-based SoftwareSerial alternatives floating around that will not stall your loop.

Comment: The standard HD44780 LCD interface is defined as a "6800 CPU bus interface" with optional 4-bit mode. That is not "sort of synchronous" nor "not an interface really" but rigidly defined in operation. The I2C and UART LCDs just provide a third party interface (IO expander, small MCU, etc) to that 6800 CPU bus interface.

Comment: UART is considered "point-to-point", so as a rule of thumb you shouldn't attach more than two devices. Usually serial LCDs come with a I2C or SPI interface, or you can use any parallel LCD connecting the required 7 pins (4 data, 3 control). Or you can use a shift register to control it (there are plenty of schematics on the internet and I think all the libraries support these modes). In any case, high-speed I2C (the 3.4Mbps one)? Are you sure the arduino uno supports this? Did you already try it? If, as I think, the uno is capped to 400kbps, I suggest you to switch to an SPI ADC (a bit faster)

Comment: @frarugi87 I meant full-speed I2C (400k) for the DAC, not high-speed - will edit. I'm only using the input side of the UART currently for MIDI, so I figured the output side would be available. Parallel LCD seems like the best solution, but I'm running short of pins, so I may have to lose some indicator LEDs if I go that route.

Comment: @RussellBorogove ok, then if you use the I2C only to communicate with the DAC (and never release it - this means you will have to write your library, since you need to never send the stop byte and the address) you will be able to continuously feed the DAC with two bytes for each sample, which are roughly 19 bits. At 400kbps, the sample rate of the signal can be at most 21 kHz. Is it enough? In my opinion it is better to switch to a SPI DAC (e.g. from the same supplier the MCP4921, or lower resolution variants MCP4911 or 4901), which is much faster to control

Comment: Yep, the requirements for a grungy bass synth are different from those for a symphony ;) I was actually using the sample-at-a-time mode of the 4725, so getting ~14khz from it — and putting it directly through a fixed lowpass at ~4500. In any case I’m probably switching to PWM output.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious option would be to get a display with SPI interface, since you have it available. Another option is to get a DAC running on SPI, and use the I2C for the display.

If you insist on using one of these 16x2 LCDs, there are SPI adapters for them as well. [Example](http://bitwizard.nl/shop/LCD-I2C-SPI-Interface-with-16x2-LCD)